# Share SQL connection between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a module that has three function:

1. Instantiates a SQL connection
2. Makes a query
3. Closes the connection

In script.js is called along with other modules (made by me) that are responsible for doing other operations that in turn require a connection to a SQL database.
My question is: `How can I pass the connection I instantiated in script.js without having it open a new connection to them?`

Thanks

Luca

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leak your connections to modules that don't need them. If a connection is needed somewhere open and close it there, and trust your DB to handle connections efficiently. Your module should only export query(), and the connection should be opened and closed inside that function.